# В каком падеже должны быть «Милосердию века» или «Страху и бледности» в контексте?

Tags: пунктуация, склонение

> В общество богов вводили и весьма отвлеченные понятия, которым даже
>   строили храмы, – например, «Милосердию века» или «Страху и бледности».

Зап/тире перед "например" переживём?

Comment: Думаю, что в родительном (это храм, а не памятник или "ода к..."), но видовое наименование "храм" перед эти не лишне было бы повторять (храм того-то и храм того-то ещё).

Comment: Тогда и "которым даже строили храмы" неверно (здесь дательный падеж)

Comment: Думаю, запятая и тире — на своем месте.

Comment: Я бы предложил такой вариант: которым даже **посвящали** храмы"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общество богов вводили и весьма отвлеченные **понятия,** которым даже строили храмы, – например, **«Милосердие века»** или «**Страх и бледность**».

Дополнение и обособленное приложение в одном падеже.